# Oracle dbms_xplan.Display() equivalent to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-execution-plan, sql-server-2017

I am converting some sql from `Oracle` to `SQL Server 2017`.

One of SQL code is having `dbms_xplan.Display()` inside the script.

I want to know what is the equivalent of `dbms_xplan.Display()` in `SQL Server 2017`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

> [SHOWPLAN_TEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-showplan-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):
>
> Causes Microsoft SQL Server not to execute Transact-SQL statements. Instead, SQL Server returns detailed information about how the statements are executed.

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON;
GO

-- your query
GO

SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT OFF;
GO
```

or if you want to execute query:

> [STATISTICS PROFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-profile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Displays the profile information for a statement. STATISTICS PROFILE works for ad hoc queries, views, and stored procedures.
>
> **When STATISTICS PROFILE is ON, each executed query returns its regular result set, followed by an additional result set that shows a profile of the query execution.**

---

Last option is to use `SHOWPLAN_XML` to get nice graphical overview in SSMS.